# What does the term "Column Collation" mean in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm using the [Open DBDiff](http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/) software to compare T-SQL tables on two different servers.One of the compare options is called "Column Collation". Could you please explain what this term means?

Comment: A collation is a specific set of characters that a column/table/DB uses. For instance UTF8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting indicates how a table will sort and index data. Here's an article that explains it in great detail:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903(v=sql.80).aspx